PowerDNS Recursor server stopped resolving about half of all domains last night; I built a new server and it's doing the same thing
I have an existing PowerDNS Recursor 4.0.4 server running on Debian Jessie 8 (I know, I know, out of date ... I'm getting to that). It handles all DNS requests for my home lab network. It has a fairly simple config and has worked without interruption for literally years at a time. It also is configured to validate and successfully validates all DNSSEC.
Last night, shortly after midnight, it stopped resolving about half of all domains worldwide, returning SERVFAIL for them. Sometimes it will resolve the primary domain (such as athenahealth.com) but not a subdomain (such as 20785-1.portal.athenahealth.com). Sometimes it will not resolve the primary domain (such as serverfault.com or askubuntu.com). I haven't been able to find any pattern, and no matter how I've mucked with my config (including turning DNSSEC completely off), it doesn't fix the problem.
My next thought was that I needed to upgrade PowerDNS Recursor, but I couldn't because of how old my DNS server was. So, I built out a brand new server running PowerDNS Recursor 5.1.3 on Ubuntu 24.04.1. Again, the config is simple. Here's the primary file:
$ cat /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf 
dnssec:
  # validation: process # default
  trustanchorfile: /usr/share/dns/root.key
recursor:
  hint_file: /usr/share/dns/root.hints
  include_dir: /etc/powerdns/recursor.d
#incoming:
 # listen:
 # - 127.0.0.1 # default
#outgoing:
 # source_address:
 # - 0.0.0.0 # default

And here's a file in recursor.d:
$ cat /etc/powerdns/recursor.d/me.yml 
dnssec:
  validation: off # validate
#  log_bogus: true
incoming:
  listen:
    - 10.20.30.76:53
logging:
  common_errors: true
  facility: 1
  loglevel: 6
  quiet: true
  trace: fail
recursor:
  auth_zones:
    - zone: my-domain-1.com
      file: /etc/powerdns/my-domain-1.com.zone
  forward_zones:
    - zone: my-domain-2.com
      forwarders:
        - 10.20.31.2
  setgid: pdns
  setuid: pdns
  socket_dir: /var/run
  write_pid: true
webservice:
  address: 10.20.30.76
  allow_from:
    - 10.20.30.0/24
    - 172.24.52.0/24
  api_key: loremipsum
  password: foobarbazqux
  port: 8080

This config is identical to my old PowerDNS Recursor config except that DNSSEC is disabled to try to get it to work. If I manually dig (I love dig) askubuntu.com from the root up, I easily find an answer:
# Using i.root-servers.net is 192.36.148.17
$ dig @192.36.148.17 com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.36.148.17 com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2217
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 21

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.               IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
com.            136670  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            136670  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
b.gtld-servers.net. 43604   IN  A   192.33.14.30
b.gtld-servers.net. 71837   IN  AAAA    2001:503:231d::2:30
l.gtld-servers.net. 44115   IN  A   192.41.162.30
l.gtld-servers.net. 74612   IN  AAAA    2001:500:d937::30
a.gtld-servers.net. 59944   IN  A   192.5.6.30
a.gtld-servers.net. 52029   IN  AAAA    2001:503:a83e::2:30
e.gtld-servers.net. 11582   IN  A   192.12.94.30
e.gtld-servers.net. 63219   IN  AAAA    2001:502:1ca1::30
m.gtld-servers.net. 27782   IN  A   192.55.83.30
m.gtld-servers.net. 50020   IN  AAAA    2001:501:b1f9::30
j.gtld-servers.net. 39663   IN  A   192.48.79.30
h.gtld-servers.net. 79936   IN  A   192.54.112.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 57527   IN  A   192.42.93.30
g.gtld-servers.net. 63219   IN  AAAA    2001:503:eea3::30
d.gtld-servers.net. 44435   IN  A   192.31.80.30
d.gtld-servers.net. 10633   IN  AAAA    2001:500:856e::30
c.gtld-servers.net. 50185   IN  A   192.26.92.30
k.gtld-servers.net. 32146   IN  A   192.52.178.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 48002   IN  A   192.43.172.30
i.gtld-servers.net. 27967   IN  AAAA    2001:503:39c1::30

$ dig @192.33.14.30 askubuntu.com NS

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.33.14.30 askubuntu.com NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46168
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 13

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;askubuntu.com.         IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
askubuntu.com.      86400   IN  NS  sureena.ns.cloudflare.com.
askubuntu.com.      86400   IN  NS  damian.ns.cloudflare.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 48087 IN  A   172.64.35.50
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 48087 IN  A   162.159.44.50
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 48087 IN  A   108.162.195.50
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 13178 IN  AAAA    2803:f800:50::6ca2:c332
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 13178 IN  AAAA    2606:4700:58::a29f:2c32
damian.ns.cloudflare.com. 13178 IN  AAAA    2a06:98c1:50::ac40:2332
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 38809 IN A   108.162.194.126
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 38809 IN A   172.64.34.126
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 38809 IN A   162.159.38.126
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 32427 IN AAAA    2a06:98c1:50::ac40:227e
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 32427 IN AAAA    2803:f800:50::6ca2:c27e
sureena.ns.cloudflare.com. 32427 IN AAAA    2606:4700:50::a29f:267e

$ dig @172.64.35.50 askubuntu.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @172.64.35.50 askubuntu.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35705
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;askubuntu.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
askubuntu.com.      300 IN  A   172.64.150.156
askubuntu.com.      300 IN  A   104.18.37.100

Perfect. But if I ask either my existing PowerDNS Recursor 4.0.4 server or my new PowerDNS Recursor 5.1.3 server, I get SERVFAIL:
$ dig @10.20.30.76 askubuntu.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @10.20.30.76 askubuntu.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 58213
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
; OPT=15: 00 16 64 65 6c 65 67 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 63 6f 6d ("..delegation com")
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;askubuntu.com.         IN  A

The OPT=15 line with some kind of signature plus delegation com is interesting. It's not happening on every domain that's failing to resolve, so it might be a red herring (and it changes ... like running that same query again resulted in OPT=15: 00 16 64 65 6c 65 67 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 73 6b 75 62 75 6e 74 75 2e 63 6f 6d ("..delegation askubuntu.com")).
Here is the PowerDNS Recursor 5.1.3 fail trace for a failed lookup of askubuntu.com: https://gist.github.com/beamerblvd/d8fa24bdf1037e2a670f8e331b7e4905
FWIW, I'm on Comcast Business Class with a 5-address static IP delegation.
What am I doing wrong?

Ultimately, a comment on this page about Comcast's "SecurityEdge" product helped me, after beating my head against the wall for more than 12 hours over this. I logged into my Comcast Business account, went to my internet service tab, scrolled to the bottom, and disabled the SecurityEdge product that had magically been enabled overnight. Suddenly all of my DNS is working perfectly again. I wasn't doing anything wrong after all. Comcast was.
Turns out their SecurityEdge product intercepts ALL DNS requests, even those made directly to authoritative servers, and inserts their own responses, which results in nonsensical answers coming from what appear to be authoritative servers but actually aren't.
Leaving this question up in case it helps someone else in the future.

Interesting. I'm seeing this here and I'm not on Comcast; perhaps someone here is doing something similar. Please come back to this in 48 hours (when it will let you mark your own response as an answer) and tag it answered; make it easier to find.
